# Including a querystring in a django.core.urlresolvers reverse() call

Tags: django, reverse, urlconf

I'm trying to reverse a named URL and include a querystring in it. Basically, I've modified the login function, and I want to send `?next=` in it.

Here's what I'm doing now: `reverse(name) + "?next=" + reverse(redirect)`

Here's what I'd like to do: `reverse(name, kwargs = { 'next':reverse(redirect) } )`

My URL for the login page (just as an example) looks like this:

`url(r'^login/', custom_login, name = 'login'),`

So how do I modify this whole thing (or call it) to include the next without having to concatenate it? It feels like an iffy solution at best.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can't capture GET parameters in the url confs, so your method is correct.

I generally prefer string formatting but it's the same thing.
`"%s?next=%s" % (reverse(name), reverse(redirect))`

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against

> The URLconf searches against the
>   requested URL, as a normal Python
>   string. This does not include GET or
>   POST parameters, or the domain name.

Comment: This is wrong. URL parameters need to be encoded, as in `"%s?%s" % (reverse(name), urlencode({"next": reverse(redirect)})`.

Comment: From Python >=3.6, for your answer, you can do the new string formatting `f"{reverse(name)}?next={reverse(redirect)}"`

Answer (score 44):

I just made my own utility function like the one asked in the question:

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode

def my_reverse(viewname, kwargs=None, query_kwargs=None):
    """
    Custom reverse to add a query string after the url
    Example usage:
    url = my_reverse('my_test_url', kwargs={'pk': object.id}, query_kwargs={'next': reverse('home')})
    """
    url = reverse(viewname, kwargs=kwargs)

    if query_kwargs:
        return f'{url}?{urlencode(query_kwargs)}'

    return url
```

Comment: In python3, the fastest way to do this would be `f'{url}?{urlencode(query_kwargs)}'`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with `reverse_lazy` since it forces evaluation :(

Answer (score 9):

I think it's better to wrap Django's reverse method to expose this API. Here's some simple code to do it:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse as django_reverse

def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, prefix=None, current_app=None):
    """
    Wrapper of django.core.urlresolvers.reverse that attaches arguments in kwargs as query string parameters
    """
    if kwargs:
        return '%s?%s' % (django_reverse(viewname, urlconf, args, None, prefix, current_app), \
                        '&'.join(['%s=%s' % (k,v) for k,v in kwargs.items()]))
    else:
        return django_reverse(viewname, urlconf, args, kwargs, prefix, current_app)
```

Put this code into some utility or common app that only depends on Django, then instead of importing django.core.urlresolvers.reverse just import myproject.myutils.urlresolvers.reverse

Answer (score 8):

I was troubled with the same question and found this [link](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25582). Apparently, your solution isn't bad designed at all. According to the ticket discussion Django won't provide this functionality.

You could use [urlobject](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/urlobject/) or [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl).

The other way, is to use your own function to do this, in a much more cleaner way. Here's the one stated in the discussion

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse as original_reverse

def reverse(*args, **kwargs):
    get = kwargs.pop('get', {})
    url = original_reverse(*args, **kwargs)

    if get:
        url += '?' + urlencode(get)

    return url
```

In the question's case, it can be used the following way

```
from [myfunctions] import reverse
...
reverse('login', get={next: reverse(redirect)})
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep the query optional, you can wrap Django's reverse function with your own function that also handles the query, allowing for other proper handling of the reverse function.

Creating a Proper Request - Note that the `query_kwargs` is optional, so you don't have to send it

```
# from a views in views.py
def sendingView(request, truckID, fleetSlug):
  #in the GET or POST
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('subAppName:urlViewName', 
                                      kwargs={'anyPassedKawrgs':goHere,…},
                                      query_kwargs={'queries': goHere}
                                      ))

# from a template in specificTemplate.html
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'subAppName:urlViewName' kwarg1=kwarg1 kwarg2=kwarg2 … query_kwargs={'dict':here} %}">Link</a>

#from a model in models.py
class Truck(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(…)
  def get_absolute_wi_url(self):
    return reverse('subAppName:urlViewName', kwargs={'kwarg1':kwarg1,'kwarg2':kwarg2})
```

In `utils.py` file (based on [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/)) for (1.11 and up?)

```
-myMainApp
  -apps
  -static
  ...
  -utils
    -__init__.py
    -utils.py

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse as django_reverse

def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None, query_kwargs=None):
  """
  Wrapper of django.core.urlresolvers.reverse that attaches arguments in kwargs as query string parameters
  """
  if query_kwargs:
    return '%s?%s' % (django_reverse(viewname, urlconf, args, kwargs, current_app), \
                    '&'.join(['%s=%s' % (k,v) for k,v in query_kwargs.items()]))
  else:
    return django_reverse(viewname, urlconf, args, kwargs, current_app)
```

In the urls conf `urls.py`

```
app_name = 'subAppName'
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^(?P<kawrg1>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(?P<kawrg2>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/path/to/here/$', views.urlViewFunctionName, name='urlViewName'),
```

And gaining access to the query

```
#in a view
def urlViewFunctionName(request, kwarg1, kwarg2):   
  if request.GET.get('submittedData'):
    submittedQuery = request.GET.get('submittedData')
else:
  submittedQuery = None
return render(request, 'trucks/weeklyInspectionSuccess.html', {
  'truck': truck,
  'submittedQuery': submittedQuery
})

#in a template
<div class="container">  
  Success for {{kwarg1}}
  {{submittedQuery}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking @chrisFrisina's idea, the robust solution is:

```py
from django.core import urlresolvers
from urllib.parse import urlencode


def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None, query_kwargs=None):
    base = urlresolvers.reverse(viewname, urlconf, args, kwargs, current_app)
    if query_kwargs:
        query = urlencode(query_kwargs)
        return f'{base}?{query}'
    else:
        return base
```