# Django - How to add on to reverse urlresolver properly

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Suppose I have this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
url = reverse('account-list')
```

Assume this leads to the URL: `/account/list/'

How do I add on to the URL? I want to make that URL this: `/account/list/1` (adding a pk value to the end of it). I know over here: [Including a querystring in a django.core.urlresolvers reverse() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995279/including-a-querystring-in-a-django-core-urlresolvers-reverse-call) it explains how to add GET parameters (e.g. `?pk=1` but I want to know if there is a proper way for me to add on to the URL (not using GET parameters)).

I'm using DRF routers: router = routers.DefaultRouter() router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet) and the user-detail view takes a pk value. So I want to do url = reverse('user-list') with /1 appended to the end of it.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You can't just add random parameters in reverse - the account-list URL actually needs to accept the parameter in the first place.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is correct. There is no reason why manual intervention to reversed urls is required in Django. However, in the end it is just a string. Add to it content, the way you would add a string.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using DRF routers: `router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)` and the `user-detail` view takes a `pk` value. So I want to do `url = reverse('user-list')` with `/1` appended to the end of it.

Comment: No, if you want to get the URL of the user-detail view you pass that name, plus the pk, to reverse, you don't try and manipulate the list URL. Why would the detail url contain "list" anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested specifically in the detail view then you shouldn't use `account-list`. Assuming you have a separate `account-detail` view (Django Rest Framework will create these for you as well when you are using default ModelViewSets, just the same as it did with `account-list`):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
u = reverse('account-detail', args=[1])
```

would be the proper way to go about this if I understand your question correctly.

You can also handle named URL parameters. For the following URL rule with a `slug` parameter:

```
url(r'/accounts/(?<slug>[a-fA-F0-9]+)/', name='account-detail', ...)
```

here's how you'd reverse the detail view for the account with a `slug` equal to `something`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
u = reverse('account-detail', kwargs={'slug': 'something'})
```